# How do I split this numpy array and reduce decimal places?

Tags: python

Given a numpy array like this:

```
prob=    [[ -1.77244641  -3.89116659  -4.92632753  -8.04921303
       -9.05286957]]
```

I wish to write them in a file separated by commas and reduce the decimal place to 4. 
This is what I have tried:

```
for pk in prob:
        jk=' '.join(str(b) for b in pk)
        f.write("("+ "%.4f" %jk + ")")
        f.write("\t")
        q=map(float, jk.split(','))
```

This however doesn't accept the decimal limiting logic and gives me an error saying float argument required no string.. I am trying to extract the probabilities and write them like this: 
`(-1.7724, -3.8911, -4.9263,  -8.0492, -9.0528)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the formatting on each string, not on the joined string.  Another thing: you said comma-separated, but you used a space to join them.  Here is what your program should look like:

```
for pk in prob:
    jk = ','.join(["%.4f" % b for b in pk])
    f.write("(" + jk + ")" + "\t")
```

Your `q = map(float, pk.split(','))` line is really useless since `pk` is already storing all of the floats.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `prob` like this:

```
prob=numpy.array([[ -1.77244641 , -3.89116659  ,-4.92632753,  -8.04921303,
   -9.05286957]])
```

And I changed your code like this:

```
 for pk in prob:
    jk=', '.join("%.4f"%b for b in pk)
    jk="("+jk+")"+"\t"
    f.write(jk)
```